# Why I'm unable to VISIBLE a included layout dynamically

Tags: android

I'm using slide up panel in my app. I want to the bottom panel is hide when the app is open first time after that I want it to visible back through java.
I'm able to hide that panel but I'm unable to show it back through java. 
here is my xml code:-

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <include
        layout="@layout/theme_red_black"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

and here is my Java code:-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .......
    bottomLayout = findViewById(R.id.bottom_panel);
    bottomLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    .......
}
```

I am using Broadcast receiver. When I receive I try to show it back but this code is not works:-

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction().equals(mStart)){
        int act = intent.getIntExtra("isStart",0);
        if(act == 1){
            setUp();
            // bottomLayout = findViewById(R.id.bottom_panel);
            bottomLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Theme_red_black xml code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/top_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.marcinmoskala.arcseekbar.ArcSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar_red"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.806"
        app:progressBackgroundColor="@color/white" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/half_circle"
        android:layout_width="426dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_half_circle" />

    <!--<com.marcinmoskala.arcseekbar.ArcSeekBar-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/volume_control"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="150dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="23dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginRight="8dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginStart="8dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginTop="8dp"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.847"-->
        <!--app:progressBackgroundColor="@color/white" />-->

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/musicArt"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="237dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/album_art_test"
        app:civ_border_color="#2F3032"
        app:civ_border_width="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.218" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Hurt"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.589" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/singer_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Singer Name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.666"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.662" />

    <!--<ImageView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/imageView7"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="36dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="36dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginRight="8dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginStart="8dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginTop="8dp"-->
        <!--android:tint="@color/white"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.974"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.015"-->
        <!--app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_like" />-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:onClick="preBtnClick"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/play"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_previous"
            android:tint="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/play"
            android:onClick="nextBtnClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_next"
            android:tint="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:onClick="playBtnClick"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.704" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.705" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/songDetails_collapse"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/default_art" />
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_180sdp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_180sdp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                    android:id="@+id/song_name_head"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_180sdp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                    android:id="@+id/singer_name_head"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:id="@+id/favorite"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/favorite"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="217dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.972"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/repeat"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_volume_down"/>
        <com.marcinmoskala.arcseekbar.ArcSeekBar
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_120sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/volume_control"
            android:layout_height="23dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_volume_up"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/shuffle"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried many ways to solve this problem but none of them works.
I did not even get any error in my android studio but it does not works.
I tried revere of it i.e 
Panel visible at onCreate method and when I get data from Broadcast receiver that I make it Invisible. This works perfectly but what I want is not working.

Comment: When setting the visibility of `bottom_panel` to `VISIBLE` make other visible layouts `INVISIBLE`. Otherwise set `elevation` of `bottom_panel`

Comment: @IREmon Sorry, but I did not understand what you said.

Comment: `android:elevation="4dp"` set this property to the `bottom_panel`

Comment: is the `onReceive()` of your `BroadcastReceiver` working well?

Comment: Post app_bar and theme_red_black xmls

Comment: Can you post full class? There are a few chances why it fails. First one is onReceive not getting if clause, or the height of sliding up panel confusing it.

Comment: @Jerrol, Yup it's working well

Comment: @VVB I have updated it

Comment: @EmreAktürk I have posted all code where I used bottom_layout variable

Comment: did you try to change the parent layout of `theme_red_black` from `ConstraintsLayout` to `LinearLayout`? I think the code is working well (and as you said), but the layout did not displaying well.

Comment: @Jerrol No I did not try it.

Comment: Ui update need to be execute in main thread. YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread kind of approach

Comment: @SunnyBhadana I think you might need to change your java code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used SlidingUpPanelLayout library and I encountered the same problem. I solved it with **PanelState**. **View.VISIBLE** and **View.GONE** **does not work** on my case too.

You can use with my workaround :

**Hide panel layout**

`slidingUpPanelLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.HIDDEN);`

**Show panel layout**

`slidingUpPanelLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED);`

Answer (score 0):

put orientation in xml file

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

or

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

else put

```
android:elevation="5dp"
```

Comment: put Log and check it out in if condition...in onReceive Method

Comment: for what if condition??

Answer (score 0):

Replace `intent.getAction().equals(mStart)` with 
`TextUtils.equals(intent.getAction(), mStart)`. You are using object equality instead content.

You can try to add `bottomLayout.requestLayout();` after `bottomLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

This might be dirty way but lets give it a try. It will re-calculate the bounds of view and drawing it again.

Also [profile your layout](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html) with [LayoutInspector](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-inspector) by navigating

> Tools -> Android -> Layout Inspector